# verilog: can not save multiple values in register

Tags: verilog, cpu-registers

I am trying to save into the register the numbers from 0 to 127. This way only the number 127 exists in the register after the execution of this code.

```
module TOP();

  reg [63:0] inputdata1;


  //pass the numbers
      integer count;

      initial
      begin
        count = 0;
        while (count < 128) // Execute loop till count is 127. exit at count 128
          begin
          // every timh that the integer variable count takes must be also passed into reg inputdata1 
          inputdata1 = count;
          count = count + 1;
        end
      end

endmodule
```

Do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: as in any programming language, the last value  wins. What did you expect? you have only one register which can contain 64 bits of data, which you overwrite every iteration in the loop.

Comment: @Serge and what type of register should I use then ?

Comment: i do not understand your question. if you want to save multiple values somewhere, you probably need an array. `reg [63:0] inputdata1[128];` or similar. Then `inputdata1[count] = count;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count` can hold a single 32-bit signed value.  `inputdata1` can hold a single 64-bit value; it can not hold multiple values at any one time.

If you add a `$display` to your code, you will see that `inputdata1` is taking on the values you expect:

```
    while (count < 128) // Execute loop till count is 127. exit at count 128
      begin
      // every timh that the integer variable count takes must be also passed into reg inputdata1 
      inputdata1 = count;
      count = count + 1;
      $display("inputdata1=%0d", inputdata1);
    end
```

Outputs:

```
inputdata1=0
inputdata1=1
inputdata1=2
inputdata1=3
inputdata1=4
etc.
```

After the `while` exits, you are left with only the last value (127).

Perhaps you want to store multiple values in an array (like a memory):

```
  reg [63:0] inputdata1 [0:127];

  // ...

    while (count < 128) begin
        inputdata1[count] = count;
        count = count + 1;
    end
```